Can I solve this limit of an integral function using L'Hopital's Rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?
$\lim _ { k \rightarrow \infty } \int _ { 1 } ^ { k } \frac { \ln x } { k \ln k } d x$
Can I solve this limit of an integral function using  L'Hopital's Rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?
I tried to search on the site, but I couldn't find anything.

Use $\int\ln x dx=x(\ln x -1)$.

Do you want to solve this not solving the integral? Because solving the integral would be a lot easier than using L'Hopital's Rule.

@user What about the lower part of the fraction? I mean I cannot distribute the integral over the denominator and the numerator as I can do with the limit.

@Nic I would like to solve it but I don't know how to solve it with both x and k existing inside the integral that's why I'm trying to use the derivative.

You evaluate the integral for a fixed $k>1$. Then you take the limit.

We can start by solving the integral.
$$ \lim_{k\to \infty} \left( \frac{x\ln(x)-x}{k\ln(k)} \right)^{x=k}_{x=1} $$
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k\ln(k)}{k\ln(k)} - \frac{k-1}{k\ln(k)} $$
We now notice that the first term is 1 and I will leave it to you to show the second term goes to 0 for large $k$.
If you are very inclined to use L'Hopital's Rule you could as follows:
$$ \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{\int_1^k \ln(x) dx}{k\ln{k}} $$
Then taking the derivative of the numerator and denominator
$$ \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{\ln(k)}{\ln(k) + 1} $$
Then I again leave it to you to do the rest.

is $k\ln{k}$ a constant, how did it get out of the integral? Isn't k supposed to be a variable? A dummy one, but a variable indeed.

It is a variable when you are looking at the limit but with respect to the integral it can be treated as a constant.

Omg I feel like I wasted one hour of my life trying to do that problem when I could simply got it out of the integral. But why is it a constant with respect to the integral, I haven't quite gotten that part.

When evaluating an integral, the only "variable" is the one you are integrating with respect to. No matter what the value of $k$ is, we can take it out of the integral so we can also take it out before it has a value. Think of it like this: $$ \int kx dx = (1/2)kx^2 $$ no matter the value of $k$ so we can also write $$ \int kx dx = k \int x dx = k(1/2)x^2 $$.

It is sort of like an identity, because $k$ has no dependence on $x$ it will be a constant for the interval you are integrating over. If $k$ had a dependence on $x$ we would not be able to do this and my above example would be completely wrong.

Okay I'll try to think about it like that. I've noticed I made a mistake in my comment when I called k a dummy variable, it's x that's a dummy variable. Sorry for that.

It should be $k-1$ instead of $k+1$ in the second formula.
